# Unique tasks ran by two worker processes at the same time using Celery

Tags: concurrency, redis, celery

I am working on a project where the goal is to run a daemon which is sending tasks to a Celery queue, Redis is used as the broker. Each task must be processed once at a time (no concurrency allowed).

To perform this, I implemented the following piece of code into my daemon, which is acting as a lock with Redis:

```
while True:    
    for foo in bar:
        if not self.redis_client.exists(foo.name):
           # Send the task to the Celery queue
           task = celery_app.send_task('buzz', context={'name': foo.name})
           redis_client.send(foo.name, task.id)
    time.sleep(10)
```

The lock is released by the task itself once it has been completed or it failed.

For some reason which I don't understand, the task is sometimes run by two worker processes at the same time :

```
[2018-04-11 15:23:45,705: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task has been executed in 101.43s for foo
[2018-04-11 15:23:45,881: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task has been executed in  114.66s for foo
```

It does not happen often, but I would not expect it to happen at all. What could explain such behaviour ? Could it be related to overhead time for Redis to write the key/value pair ?

As an additional info, I also have a Flower instance running on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of missing details here, but I'll try to help:
Due to your requirements - no concurrency - I'll guess that you have only one celery worker running. 
When you run this worker you can specify the concurrency level by `-c` flag (or `--concurrency`) - make sure you set it to 1 so only one instance of that worker will live at a time. ref [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency)

For example: `celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=1 -n worker1@%h`

Another thing that you should be aware of is the `worker_prefetch_multiplier` which prefetch by default 4 messages at a time. You might want to change it to 1 as well (I guess you didn't describe your full scenario). ref [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-prefetch-multiplier)

Last thing, about your redis locks, consider use SETNX (set if not exist) - more info - [here](https://redis.io/commands/setnx)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your hints ! You guessed right about what I am currently using (I am new at building Celery-based architecture). I will try all your advices and looked if SETNX has been implemented in redis-py.

Comment: @DrMouse NP, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;-)